# Invariance of Killing Form

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm currently learning about Killing Forms and I came across this important property: up to scalar multiples, every simple Lie Algebra has a unique bilinear form that is invariant under all automorphisms of the Lie Algebra.

My question is: why would we *want* a bilinear form to be invariant? That is, if we act on a Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ by a linear map, then aren't we changing the geometry of the Lie Algebra (e.g: scaling it in some direction, or skewing it), as most linear maps do? In that case, we wouldn't *want* the bilinear form to remain invariant under all those changes! My intuition is that most linear maps (on general vector spaces) do not leave inner products invariant, so why would we require that property in this case? Thanks for the help!

Comment: When studying objects, we want tools to play with. Having a uniquely defined thing gives us a tool.

Comment: Okay, but why do we want our tool to be $\text{ad}$-invariant? That's the question.

Comment: In general, in math and physics you aim for maximal level of symmetry possible. Your intuition of distortion by adjoint action is based on Euclidean geometry, which gives wrong model. Lorentzian geometry of sl(2, R) provides a better intuition.

Comment: Objects that do not respect the group of symmetries you have cannot in general offer any information about your group. There are many many *many* bilinear forms on a space. Exactly one of them is ad-invariant. So which do you think is more useful? The unique object, or the one drop in the ocean of symmetry-breaking forms?

Answer (score 2):

One reason is that we obtain a bi-invariant metric.
In fact, the following are equivalent:

- The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g} $ of the Lie group $G$ admits an $\text{Ad}$-invariant inner product,
- The Lie group $G$ admits a bi-invariant metric,

[Which Lie groups have Lie algebras admitting an Ad-invariant inner product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319593/which-lie-groups-have-lie-algebras-admitting-an-ad-invariant-inner-product)